# British Naturalisation - Past Employment

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I have already started an application for the British citizenship and I have some questions as I do not want to deal with any failure.

I get a message that I must provide my employment history for the past 10 years or since you have been in the UK. In some cases, it is really difficult to find the exact start and end dates or even the exact employer names. My questions are:

a) Should I rely on the P45 documents I have? What if the official employment has different ones? For example, I left one company and used the holidays left for the last 3 days. Is the official end date needed what is mentioned in the P45 or the last day of work including the 3 days of holidays?

b) Does it have to be precise when it comes to the names of the employers? In my contract for instance I have a name "XXX Ltd." and in the HRMC page and the income tax, I can see a different one "XXX Shared".

c) Address of employer can either be what is stated in the P45 or P60 or the office I worked for? Is that correct?

d) Is there an easy way to get the exact start and end dates of employment from HRMC without having to hire a solicitor? I have only found a form which needs to be sent via post but nothing online.

Note that I have a settled status (ILR)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A) Your P45 shows the date your contract of employment ended and what will be recorded on your HMRC record so use that. If you don't know the exact date, just put the month and year.

B) Often, companies use "trading as" names or are subsidiaries of a parent company that manages the payroll. I suggest you include both names along with the PAYE reference number from your P45/P60 (three digits / alpha-numerical).

C) Again, I suggest you use both just to be sure but make it clear who your employer was.

D) Post the form, or just send a letter, to HMRC asking for a breakdown of your employment history - don't forget to cite your NINO and home address(es). NB their on-line service may not be able to process this type of request.

Comment: I am not sure I can leave the day empty. I will try. It is not that easy to find information about this matter. It might be important for the people who will validate the data before accepting my application.